# Displaying object in html and getting : "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays"

Tags: angular

I got this json from rest api call

```
{"items":[{"id":"1","name":"Adam","age":20},{"id":"2","name":"Cris","age":32}]}
```

From Api I got an object UserResult which contains list of specific users objects. 
I would like to display in html file values for all user objects -  names for every user.

```
<div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let name of user">
        <div>
            <span>{{user.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

My data.service looks like:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public getUsers(): Observable<UserResult> {
    return this.httpClient.get<UserResult>(baseUrl);
  }
}
```

and component.ts looks like this:

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  users: UserResults;


  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  private getUsers() {
    this.dataService.getUsers().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.users = data;
      }
    )
  }
}
```

As I understand from this error I can not display values for specific object the way I try.

```
 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Should I create let's say an array with type User and then try to display in html every single user?

Map my api response from UserResults to `users:User[]` ? 
Or is there other way to do it?

Comment: this.users = data.items;  you are missing items and then in object items is the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify your Component as below:

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  users: UserResults;


  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  private getUsers() {
    this.dataService.getUsers().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.users = data.items;
      }
    )
  }
}
```

then you can use `users` in your Template like below:

```
<div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let name of users">
        <div>
            <span>{{user.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate `ng-container` using `user.items`.

```
<div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let user of user.items">
        <div>
            <span>{{user.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Your array is located inside `user` object and to use `{{user.name}}`, you need to declare `let user of user.items` instead of `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the statement with `*ngFor="let name of user.items"`.

The array is in the property `items`.

```html
<div>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let name of user?.items">
    <div>
      <span>{{user.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```